# Web service (asmx) one instance multiple clients?

Tags: c#, web-services, configuration, asmx

I was wondering if anybody knows if it is possible to setup a traditional web service running in .net 2.0 so that there is:
 - One instance of the web service
 - Several clients using this one instance

Is the default behavior that multiple clients will have their own instance of the service or is there only ever one instance? Reading suggests that this has to be configured somehow but not sure how.

Comment: Not completely clear what do you want here. What is "one instance of the web service"?

Comment: As in is the web service static, i.e. client 1 and client 2 access the web service, will both have their own instance of the service or is it shared?

Comment: Client 1 and Client 2 will share single application instance, but each of them will have own Request, Response, Session etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.asmx web services are hosted in IIS and thus, are technically web apps running in the app pool, so the app pool setting will specify the Maximum Number of Worker Processes. See the "Web Garden" section here for a better explanation. This all applies to web services hosted in IIS as well as ASP.NET apps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720391(v=vs.71).aspx